# Run executable on system startup on debian

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, executable, startup

I would like to do the following on system startup on debian:

```
./home/user/bittorrent_sync_i386/btsync
```

I downloaded the application here:

http://download-new.utorrent.com/endpoint/btsync/os/linux-i386/track/stable

The error I get is:

```
"bash ./home/user/bittorrent_sync_i386/btsync: File or directory not found."
```

I only can do:

```
cd /home/user/bittorrent_sync_i386/
./btsync
```

I would just like to run the application on startup on debian. I also found this:

http://xmodulo.com/how-to-automatically-start-program-on-boot-in-debian.html

But how would I modify this script to do what I want? Sorry I am quite new to debian.

Comment: This sounds like a question to post in either [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) as it does not seem to have much to do with programming which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. To try and answer your question anyway: see tag `@reboot` for cron (more info with `man 5 crontab`).

Comment: Ok thank you. I didn't know that this site is limited to programming only.

Comment: Before posting anything anywhere, it is always a good policy to read rules first. Consider taking a look at [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what is the topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you launch

```
/home/user/bittorrent_sync_i386/btsync
```

Without the dot. Does it work better ?

Comment: I don't believe it. It is really that simple and it works. Thank you! Just out of curiosity... is this the correct syntax for Ubuntu too? I thought that it was the syntax with the dot and this would surprise me since it is a debian derivate. Anyways thanks again. You helped me a lot!

Comment: The dot is used only if you are in the correct folder.
If you aren't you need to start with "/" :)